# Why does Linux 3.2 kernel (Debian backport) hang during boot?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, backports

I wanted to upgrade the Linux kernel on my Debian wheezy (stable) on Thinkpad T60. I installed `linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.4-686-pae`, version 3.2.41-2~bpo60+1. The problem is it hangs during boot, just after `Cleaning ifupdown....` with

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s
```

Is there anything I can do about it, or is it a kernel bug? I've never experienced this problem with older 2.6.x kernels.

[image]

Comment: Not really an expert or anything, but have you tried removing the "quiet" kernel boot parameter to get more verbose output?

Comment: Is there a newer kernel package available for it? Most recent long term support kernel is 3.4.46.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to what's happening is that it hung in `modprobe`: it's probably hung trying to load a module for a piece of hardware.

Stuff to try:

- add `noapic` to the kernel command line, and make sure `quiet` isn't present so you can see what's going on
- make sure your laptop's BIOS is at the latest version
- if you do manage to figure out which module is causing the hang, boot from a recovery CD and add modules to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Seems that the problem was caused by module `lirc_sir`. After removing it, the kernel boots. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Potential issue #1

I found an issue similar to yours covered over in this Server Fault Q&A titled: [How to fix “BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 17163091968s”?](https://serverfault.com/questions/336591/how-to-fix-bug-soft-lockup-cpu0-stuck-for-17163091968s). Perhaps it's related to your issue as well.

#### Potential issue #2

Another issue in launchpad, sounds similar to yours. Issue's title: [BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [kworker/0:3:566]; RIP: 0010:[] [] mei_timer+0xc3/0x260 [mei]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1011914). The workaround for this issue was to update to a newer kernel.

#### Workarounds?

In general I would advise you to try upgrading to a newer kernel for starters only to confirm that the issue is with your combination of hardware + kernel version.